# Add number to the right hand side of an item in latex

Tags: equations, numbering

The following is my equation in Latex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\sum_{l\in L} \sum_{s\in S_{l}} I_{fs} \times x_{ls}+y_{f}=1,\forall f\in F$     
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

What I am interested in, is adding a number to the right side of this equation. I was wondering if there is a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item []
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{l\in L} \sum_{s\in S_{l}} I_{fs} \times x_{ls}+y_{f}=1,\forall
  f\in F
\end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works. Will flag it green as soon as the system allows me. Thanks so much!

Comment: @NavidRashedi, you are welcome.